# Using protected (no copy/paste) pdf

Tags: pdf, pdf-reader

I'm using PDF-XChange to view pdf's. I have one pdf that has lock on it:

[image]

And I can't copy text from it:

[image]

How to solve copy/paste problem?

Comment: Why is this pdf locked?

Comment: Where is "existing question"?

Answer (score -1):

It seems that this PDF file was secured using the "password security" option, with some usage restrictions applied [(https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/securing-pdfs-passwords.html)](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/securing-pdfs-passwords.html).

To copy and paste text from such PDF file, you should at first remove security, using a tool like QPDF [(http://qpdf.sourceforge.net/)](http://qpdf.sourceforge.net/), invoking it with a syntax like this:

```
qpdf --decrypt encrypted.pdf decrypted.pdf
```